# open google map in iphone not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using this code to open Google maps in Swift and it is not working.

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
        "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
} else {
    print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

It always shows the message "Can't use comgooglemaps://"

- I have added comgooglemaps to the plist file
- I have restarted Xcode many times
- I have restarted the laptop
- I have tried on simulator and real device

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

**EDIT**

info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>googlechromes</string>
            <string>googlephotos</string>
        <string>telprompt</string>
        <string>tel</string>
        <string>http</string>
        <string>https</string>
    </array>
```

**EDIT2**

```
let url1:NSURL = NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!;
         let url2:NSURL = NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(self.selectedItem.latitude),\(self.selectedItem.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!;
         let url3:NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=\(self.selectedItem.latitude),\(self.selectedItem.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!;


        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url1))
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url2)
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url3)
        }
```

Comment: which version of swift?

Comment: Show the relevant portion of your Info.plist where you added comgooglemaps.

Comment: And of course this will never work in the simulator and it will only work on a real iOS device if the device has the Google maps app installed.

Comment: @rmaddy please check the edit

Comment: And do you have the Google maps app installed on a real device?

Comment: @rmaddy no it is not installed, will install it and try again

Comment: Can't open an app that isn't installed.

Comment: @rmaddy is there any way to open it on web page if the app is not installed

Comment: it's ridiculous how app not open without installation  , you can try canOpen method of UIapplication.shared if not navigate to this link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-gps-navigation/id585027354?mt=8 Note copy the link from addressBar

Comment: I'm not positive but I think if you try to open a URL starting with `https://maps.google.com/...` then the Google Maps app will be used if installed and Safari will be launched if not.

Comment: @rmaddy I modified the code to open web if app not found, the web is working fine but the app is still not opening, will try to restart the phone and the laptop and hopefully it will work, Thanks a lot

Comment: 1. Use the same URL in both `canOpenURL` and `openURL`. 2. Are you testing on a real device? 3. Did you install the Google Maps app on the device? 4. My suggestion of using `https://maps.google.com` meant you don't need to use or check for "comgooglemaps".

Comment: @rmaddy it works after I install google map, and I handle also if the app is not open to open safari with url, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private var latitude = 30.7333
private var longitude = 76.7794

/// Open Maps Action
@IBAction func openMapsAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.openGoogleMaps()
}

//MARK: Open Google maps
func openGoogleMaps(){
   // Open in Google Maps
   if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL))
   {
       /// Driving google map
       UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(self.latitude),\(self.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   }
   else
   {
       print("Can't use Google Maps");
   }
}
```

**Keys Required**

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
 <string>googlechromes</string>
 <string>comgooglemaps</string>
 </array>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Please explain how this answer helps. You have posted the same code with the same relevant entry for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Please read the comments. The only reason the OP couldn't run Google Maps with what they posted in their question was the simple fact that they did not have the Google Maps app installed.